# Can i send volley request from activity and use the response in the fragments?

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-activity, android-volley

I am sending a Volley request from activity.I want to access the result in two fragments.Is it possible.If Possible how can i access these values in fragments.I want to access all the text1 to text6 in one fragment and remaining pojo array in another fragment or For two responses do i need to send two requests from two fragments??
The below is the reponse

{
  "text1": "lion_1",
  "text2": "lion_2",
  "text3": "lion_3",
  "text4": "lion_4",
  "text5": "lion_5",
  "text6": "lion_6",
  "pojo": [
    {
      "medium": "lion_1.jpe",
      "name": "lion_1"
    },
    {
      "medium": "lion_2.jpe",
      "name": "lion_2"
    },
    {
      "medium": "lion_3.jpe",
      "name": "lion_3"
    },
    {
      "medium": "lion_4.jpe",
      "name": "lion_4"
    },
    {
      "medium": "lion_5.jpe",
      "name": "lion_5"
    },
    {
      "medium": "lion_6.jpe",
      "name": "lion_6"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Yes you can do so .

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.

Here's how you could go about communicating your response from the main activity.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FragOne fragOne;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...

        fragOne = new FragOne();
        //add fragment


    }

    void onResponse(String response){
        fragOne.getNetworkResponse(response);
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
class FragOne extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }

    public void getNetworkResponse(string responce){
        //process response here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it ispossible. First, you need to parse Json response in background and save it in activity. When web call and parsing is complete, notify fragments about new data. You may create some interface for fetching particular data by fragmentsm implement it in activity. Each fragment will cast activity to that interface and get data it need (if ther is any). To tell fragment that ther is new data available, you may create interface and implement it in new data, or just create new fragment instance every time and get data from activity

Answer (score 0):

The answers here always wait for the request to finish and then proceed to the fragment and also coupling Activity and the fragment

however I would decouple the activity from the fragment.

IMO I would like to add requests to the queue form any place and receive responses in any place without places know about themselves nor passing data around. One way to achieve this using RxJava and observing responses based on the request tags.

I have created a library [jus](https://github.com/apptik/jus) based on Volley where you can plugin RxJava and easily achieve this behavior:

in one fragment:

```
//Calls the API (adds requests to the queue)     
MyJus.intructablesApi().list(20,0, Instructables.SORT_RECENT,"id");
//starts the other fragment
frag = InstructablesListFragment.newInstance();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, frag)
            .commit();
```

in the other fragment:

```
     RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RxAdapter(
MyJus.hub().get(REQ_LIST).map(o -> ((ResultEvent) o).response));
```

where the hub gather all the responses from all the requests and arranges them by concepts.

you can check the full example [in github](https://github.com/apptik/jus/tree/master/sample-android):